# Auto ajustar todos los controles de manera automática (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas tardes, ¿Es posible de alguna manera que todos los controles que tengo en un formulario se adapten de alguna manera al maximizar dicho formulario?
Teniendo en cuenta que tengo botones, textbox, controltabs... no se si seria posible de hacerlo de manera automática.
He intentado meterlos en grupos dentro de controles splitter containers pero después si a un control pongo un FILL en la propiedad "dock" este solapa a los demás controles que estan dentro de ese contenedor...
Entiendo que debe haber una manera de autoajuste ya que en principio esta aplicación se ejecutara en monitores de varias resoluciones.

Seria pasar de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero claro, teniendo en cuenta que por ejemplo lo unico que tendria que no todo tiene que agrandarse de la misma manera... La barra de abajo gris, debe tener siempre la misma altura pero cambiar su propiedad de anchura

Muchas gracias

---

te cuento lo que me esta pasando... añado un table layout y la ultima columna se queda con el tamaño de creacion pero las otras dos se cambian en funcion del tamaño... ¿Como controlas cuales se mueven y cuales no?
No entiendo bien la filosofia de este control...

Una imagen vale mas que mil palabras...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna de la derecha es la mas ancha... Pero si estiro el form...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna de la derecha mantiene su anchura y las otras dos se estiran... claro, a mi me interesa poder estirar solo las que me interesen...

¿Es posible?

Muchas gracias

Edito: Haciendo mas pruebas veo que unas veces se quedan fijas unas columnas, otras veces otras... dependiendo de las opciones que voy tocando (Size Mode "Autoajuste", "Porcentaje", "Absoluto"...) Pero sin coherencia aparente

Comment: Ese es uno de los grandes problemas de winforms, y una de las cosas por las que microsoft creo WPF. La mejor opción para que todo cuadre como debe ser es usar [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/3a1tbfwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: es windows form o wpf?

Comment: Mira un ejemplo en este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSmjhwU_SWQ) usando `FlowLayoutPanel` o este otro [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-ZNjvKXBUU) ,(Solo como muestra de como usarlo), aunque realmente en `WindowsForms` no hay muchas opciones disponibles para hacer las aplicaciones `responsivas` en cambio en WPF si.

Comment: Dale un vistazo a la propiedad [Control.Anchor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=net-5.0) que está presente en todos los controles.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar los tabletlayoutpanel es un tipo de tabla que se auto ajusta, debes crear las columnas y filas y en cada casilla agregaras los elementos, no es fácil pero si funciona[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se visualiza normal
después maximizado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

finalmente te muestro la parte de diseño un poco para que veas como se manejan los tabletlayoutpanel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Eder!

Estoy probando un poco con los TableLayout y no veo la logica que utiliza a la hora de expandir el formulario... 
Por las pruebas que hago... Solamente cambian de tamaño las dos columna mas a la izquierda pero las demas se quedan intactas manteniendo la anchura original... Da igual  crear 3, 4, 5 o 6...
¿tiene alguna logica "coherente"?

Gracias!

Comment: Se me paso decirte algo en cada celda del tabletlayout yo coloque un panel el cual se expandirá a todo el ancho de la celda del table layout...¿porque el panel? bueno así en una celda podre colocar varios elementos y se expandirán gradualmente. ahora en el tablet layout busca la propiedad  anchor y ahí seleccionar hacia donde quieres que se expanda el tablet layou.... en las imágenes tengo dos tablet layout el primero se expande hacia arriba y hacia los lados el segundo que es el que contiene el datagriew de color azul se expande hacia abajo y hacia los lados para que no choquen

Comment: me comentas como te fue